# How to read and write RFID using flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, nfc

Is it possible to develop an NFC reader app using Flutter? If yes, can someone suggest a method to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to develop an NFC reader app using Flutter. You can use the `nfc_manager` package or the `flutter_nfc_kit` package to implement NFC functionality.

You can look at the [nfc_manager documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager) and the [flutter_nfc_kit documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit) for information and instructions.

After reading about both, you can choose the one you think will be most effective for your app.